# Byte sequence for changing MIDI channel balance

Tags: midi

I am generating and playing sound over MIDI messages. I need to do some stereo effect (change balance) but I can't find solution.

Now I am trying to use "Chan 1 Control/Mode Change" messages with parameters "08" (first byte) and "0..127" (second byte) but this doesn't work. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your first byte must actually be indicating that you want to send a control change message, and on what channe.  [Use `0xB0` to send CC on channel 1](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php) before sending the CC number and then value.

Not all devices are going to respond to all CC messages.  If you're sending `0x08` and `0x00` - `0x7F` and nothing is happening, you probably have such a device.

You might also be trying to change panning instead, which would be `0x0A` (10 DEC).

Comment: I send message with bytes: 0xB0 + 0x08 + 0x00..0xFF Is it correct for changing balance on channel 1?

Comment: The upper limit for data bytes is 0x7f.

Comment: Ok, is 0xB0+0x08+0x00..0x7F correct? It is still not working but chaning volume over 0xB0+0x07+0x00..0x8F is working great? Thank for advice.

Comment: @user2329752 In that case, your synthesizer probably doesn't support panning or balance.

Comment: Panning is working, only balance not. Synthesizer is my sound card - I play generate sound over my sound card on headset?

Comment: @user2329752 You're probably using the software synth on your system, and it is typical to panning only since many synths are mono.